# Multithreading when serving cached data from app engine

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine, gwt, memcached

I have a very simple question and could not find an answer, which makes me think that I am most likely missing some basic facts.

I am using memcache to cache and serve large static data, which should generally enable us serving thousands of users from a single instance; however, it seems like that since app engine is single threaded, every request is queued and served in sequence and then ultimately starts multiple instances when serving a lot of users…

Aside from the latency and especially when starting new instances, this causes even a much bigger pricing problem. Since Google is now charging for instance hours rather than CPU utilization, and by serving cached data, we are most likely just using a fraction of the available CPU from each instance and therefore being charged for many unnecessary additional instances, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344484/appengine-instance-hours-vs-cpu-time) post…

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for your answer

Comment: why are you serving static data from memcache, couldn't it be a static resource ?

Comment: Well, in that sense it's dynamic. These are resources, which have very little writes and many reads, however generated after compiling...

Comment: appengine isn't single threaded on java, and in the last year python support for threads (though not as efficient as we would like). My python single threaded site can typically serve relatively static content (CMS) in < 20msec from memcache.

Comment: Do you have a link, which explains how to do Java multithreading on app engine?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Using_Concurrent_Requests

Comment: Can this work when each request is from a different source/user? We should be able to serve cached data in a multithreading environment in < 1 ms, see http://code.google.com/p/stick-cache/

Comment: Yes, memcache is a shared network cache.  Any shared network cache is going to have some latency - in googles case its going to be the round trip time doing the RPC to the memcache service.  You could also structure an instance level cache. However its harder to invalidate instance level caches. You need to be able to tell the instance to reload it's cache if any writes occur, and you need to tell all instances to reload.

Comment: note your reference to stick-cache - the 1ms response time is for in memory cache and not memcache.

Comment: Well, that's exactly my point. If we can have multithreading, then one instance can serve thousands of simultaneous requests, from its in memory cache...

Comment: Are you making a point or asking a question.  You need to test you app and then configure the amount of resources accordingly. So test it with multithreading enabled, run a real workload (with a slow ramp up) see how many instances you actually require to service the load.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable multi-threading by setting the "threadsafe" element to "true" in the appengine-web.xml file then App Engine is no longer single threaded.

But, caching data in MemCache doesn't mean you can serve an unlimited number of requests from a single instance. Mem cache is not running your application code, it just saves you going to the datastore for it and hence is faster.

Depending on your code and memory usage etc, then when App Engine sees the one instance (now serving multiple requests at a time due to multi-threading) get "too busy" it will start-up new instances (this depends on MANY dashboard settings and also on your warm-up requests setting in appengine-web.xml) and newer requests maybe served by those.

So, instance usage depends on the duration of the code serving your requests coming in, and each one's memory usage - not MemCache.

If by saying "static data", you are referring to html files etc, by amrking them as "static" in the appengine-web.xml, then in fact you may not need any instances at all. They are served by Google's COntent Distribution Network ("CDN") without starting your instances or running any of your code.

For that to happen, then a client request (e.g. from a browser) would need to ONLY request static files, and not cause any of your application code to be run.

So, based on all that - you might need to reformulate your question - either way I hope it helped.